# Does this box plot indicate that an extreme value exists?

Tags: boxplot, extreme-value, cauchy-distribution

[image]

This is the boxplot of the data. Did Extreme Value occur in this data?

Comment: This boxplot is, it seems, using a common rule that points should be plotted individually if they lie more than 1.5 IQR from the nearer quartile. What that means is specific to the dataset and the goals of the analysis, but what this box plot tells me is: skewness is so marked that one should transform!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What do you mean by "an extreme value exists"? Are you asking if this looks like an *extreme value distribution*? Or are you asking about outliers? (in which case it depends on what your definition of an extreme value is)

Comment: extreme value about outliers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no universal agreement on what an "extreme value" is, exactly. And, in practice, it depends on context.

Your variable C7 is clearly very skewed. Whether the highest value is an outlier is not as clear.  And what is C7? And what does a value of about 7200 mean?

Comment: flood quantile from various station..  so can i say it extreme value? because the data cannot be discarded.

Comment: I don't know.  You tell me.  Is 7000 an extreme value or not?  What are you doing with the variable? Why do you care about the shape of the distribution?

Comment: Because if it an extreme value. I want to used Cauchy distribution in simulation study. Or you have another method to detect extreme value in data set?

Comment: +1. Also, box plots assume a normal-ish distribution. So it does appear that the data is skewed. Extreme Value" has a specific meaning in some fields of statistics, so the equally vague "outlier" is probably a better term. The OP needs to specify the data because it could be multiplicative in nature (i.e. would box plot nicely with a log transform), etc.

Comment: Pretty much the first rule of statistical hydrology is to think of discharge on a logarithmic scale.